# How to load a single model in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: model, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to load a model to add dirty data to the store, but can't seem to load up the actual model to then setData to it...

Doing this:

```
var model = Ext.ModelMgr.getModel("AT.model.Booking");
```

returns:

```
function () {
    return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Which doesn't seem right at all. I found a thread about this; 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?177658-How-to-get-a-single-model

The following bug report states that it should be fixed in following versions but it doesn't seem to be... I'm not sure how to integrate the fix mentioned in the bug report...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but the argument to pass to the `getModel` method is the `id` of the model you want to get. You seem to be passing it the class name of a model.

Unless `AT.model.Booking` is an `id` for an actual model instance. Which seems weird to me but it's none of my business then :P

Comment: The id you say? I thought ST2 was all about not using id's but xtypes and classnames?

Comment: Docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.ModelManager-method-getModel

Comment: Actually, it says it can be either id or model instance. And if you look at the section on the page you sent me; Accessing Model Types, then is specifically says that it should be possible to do what I was trying to do. Which it doesn't.

Comment: It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do, which is return the model class. If you need to create an instance of this model class, you need to use `Ext.create("AT.model.Booking")` . I think that is what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to accomplish but if you want to save a single record get the model off the DB and then call save().

```
var model = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('AT.model.Booking');

model.load(id, {
  scope: this,

  success: function(record) {
    if (profile.dirty) {
      profile.save();
    }
  },

  failure: function() {
    console.log('Something went wrong.');
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you load a single model.

```
var thing;
AT.model.Booking.load(thingId, {
  success: function(rec) { 
    thing = rec; 
  } 
});
```

A gotcha is that you have to have your proxy settings setup on your model in it's "config" section. This syntax is a little more straightforward than the whole "getmodel" thing.